# Adding custom value to AmLegend valueText/periodValueText in AmXYChart

Tags: legend, amcharts, legend-properties

I am trying to plot line chart with AmXYChart instead of serial chart as I wanted to update all the line independently on a real-time basis. And also wanted to update valueText in legend for all line graphs dynamically.

I am able to get valueText and periodValueText in case of AmSerialChart but unable to get or set it in case of AmXYChart. Following is my legend setting in serial chart:

```
"legend": {
    "valueWidth": 100,
    "valueAlign": "left",
    "valueText": "[[close]]",
    "periodValueText": "[[value.close]]",
},
```

Any help will be appreciated, Either by amChart settings or by custom way.

Comment: Am I going right in assuming you are using amcharts3? Can you provide your complete config please or create an code pen? At the moment it quite impossible to guess where your error could be.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp Its resolved now, Actually AmXYChart does not support "valueText": "[[close]]". This feature is only supported by AmSerialChart.